# Sum across partitions with window functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, window-functions

I have the following problem...

```
    Time |  A   |  B |  C  --  Sum should be
      1     a1     b1   c1     a1 + b1 + c1
      2     a2     b2   x      a2 + b1 + c1 
      3     a3     x    x      a3 + b2 + c1
      4     x      b3   c2     a3 + b3 + c2
```

Essentially, the sum needs to be across the most recent value
in time for each of the three rows.  Each data column doesn't
necessarily have a value for the current time.

I have tried several approaches using window functions and
have been unsuccessful. I have written a stored procedure that
does what I need, but it is SLOW.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION timeseries.combine_series(id int[], startTime timestamp, endTime timestamp) 
RETURNS setof RECORD AS $$
DECLARE
    retval double precision = 0;
    row_data timeseries.total_active_energy%ROWTYPE;
    maxCount integer = 0;
    sz integer = 0;
lastVal double precision[];
v_rec RECORD;
BEGIN   
    SELECT INTO sz array_length($1,1);

    FOR row_data IN SELECT * FROM timeseries.total_active_energy  WHERE time >= startTime AND time < endTime AND device_id = ANY($1) ORDER BY time
       LOOP
    retval = row_data.active_power;
    for i IN 1..sz LOOP
        IF $1[i]=row_data.device_id THEN
            lastVal[i] = row_data.active_power;
        ELSE
            retval = retVal + COALESCE(lastVal[i],0);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    SELECT row_data.time, retval into v_rec;

    return next v_rec;
     END LOOP;

      return ;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
select * from timeseries.combine_series('{552,553,554}'::int[], '2013-05-01'::timestamp, '2013-05-02'::timestamp) 
    AS (t timestamp with time zone, val double precision);
```

Comment: I assume that's supposed to be a2 + **b2** + c1 in your second row?

Comment: The query should return the the sum.  The summation is always done on the fly.

Comment: There should be an solution for your new question. But I am asking you to comply with the customs around here first. Create a **new question**, don't change the nature of an existing question after an answer has been given. I have rolled back your offending edit. You can see your changes in the version history. Also, while being at it: a test case should provide simple data. You new test case was needlessly complex which does not help to present the problem. And add your version of Postgres, please.

Comment: In the process of adding a new question...  Thank you

Comment: I think I have an interesting solution ...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ts, a, b, c
       , COALESCE(max(a) OVER (PARTITION BY grp_a), 0)
       + COALESCE(max(b) OVER (PARTITION BY grp_b), 0)
       + COALESCE(max(c) OVER (PARTITION BY grp_c), 0) AS special_sum
FROM  (
   SELECT *
         ,count(a) OVER w AS grp_a
         ,count(b) OVER w AS grp_b
         ,count(c) OVER w AS grp_c
   FROM   t
   WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY ts)
   ) sub
ORDER  BY ts;
```

First, put actual values and following `NULL` values in a group with the aggregate window function `count()`: it does not increment with `NULL` values.

Then take `max()` from every group, arriving at what you are looking for. At this point you could just as well use `min()` or `sum()`, since there is only one non-null value per group.

`COALESCE()` catches `NULL` values if the overall first value in time is `NULL`.

Note how I picked `ts` as column name, since I don't use base type names like `time` as identifiers.

#### Test case

That's also how you everyone should provide sample data in the first place!

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t (ts int, a int, b int, c int);

INSERT INTO t VALUES
  (1, 11,   21,   NULL)
 ,(2, 12,   22,   NULL)
 ,(3, 13,   NULL, NULL)
 ,(4, NULL, 23,   32);
```

Comment: Apologies for not providing data and now I realize I didn't state the problem correctly.  Again, thank you.  Editing

Comment: @user2505340: I appreciate how you are trying to get your question right. But it is generally not accepted around here to change the nature of a question after answers have been given. Instead, create a new different question and roll back the changes to this one.