# Sum a sequence of device-labeled, data using most recent data for device

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab, window-functions

I am using Postgres 9.2.

I have the following problem:

```
Time | Value | Device   --  Sum should be
1      v1      1              v1 
2      v2      2              v1 + v2 
3      v3      3              v1 + v2 + v3 
4      v4      2              v1 + v4 + v3
5      v5      2              v1 + v5 + v3
6      v6      1              v6 + v5 + v3
7      v7      3              v6 + v5 + v3
```

Essentially, the sum needs to be across the most recent value
in time for each of the N devices.  In the example above, there
are 3 devices.

I have tried several approaches using window functions and
have been unsuccessful. I have written a stored procedure that
does what I need, but it is SLOW.   The SLOWness could be my
lack of experience with plpgsql.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION timeseries.combine_series(id int[], startTime timestamp, endTime timestamp) 
RETURNS setof RECORD AS $$
DECLARE
    retval double precision = 0;
    row_data timeseries.total_active_energy%ROWTYPE;
    maxCount integer = 0;
    sz integer = 0;
lastVal double precision[];
v_rec RECORD;
BEGIN   
    SELECT INTO sz array_length($1,1);

    FOR row_data IN SELECT * FROM timeseries.total_active_energy  WHERE time >= startTime AND time < endTime AND device_id = ANY($1) ORDER BY time
       LOOP
    retval = row_data.active_power;
    for i IN 1..sz LOOP
        IF $1[i]=row_data.device_id THEN
            lastVal[i] = row_data.active_power;
        ELSE
            retval = retVal + COALESCE(lastVal[i],0);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    SELECT row_data.time, retval into v_rec;

    return next v_rec;
     END LOOP;

      return ;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
select * from timeseries.combine_series('{552,553,554}'::int[], '2013-05-01'::timestamp, '2013-05-02'::timestamp) 
    AS (t timestamp with time zone, val double precision);
```

Sample data

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE t (ts int, active_power real, device_id int, should_be int);

INSERT INTO t VALUES
 (1,2,554,2)
,(2,3,553,5)
,(3,9,553,11)
,(4,7,553,9)
,(5,6,552,15)
,(6,8,554,21)
,(7,5,553,19)
,(8,7,553,21)
,(9,6,552,21)
,(10,7,552,22)
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am building on my answer to your previous question, where you presented a simpler case. Read there for an explanation of the window functions aspect of the solution:

- [Sum across partitions with window functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215116/sum-across-partitions-with-window-functions/17216001#17216001)

This question presents a "unpivoted" data-set. To get to where you want to be, you could run a cross tabulation first, reducing the case to its simpler, previous form.
PostgreSQL has the additional module [**tablefunc**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html) providing very fast functions for that. Run this command *once per database* to install:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

Then all you need is this (including redundant columns in the result for debugging):

```sql
SELECT ts, active_power, device_id, should_be
     , COALESCE(max(a) OVER (PARTITION BY grp_a), 0)
     + COALESCE(max(b) OVER (PARTITION BY grp_b), 0)
     + COALESCE(max(c) OVER (PARTITION BY grp_c), 0) AS special_sum
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , count(a) OVER w AS grp_a
        , count(b) OVER w AS grp_b
        , count(c) OVER w AS grp_c
   FROM   crosstab(
            'SELECT ts, active_power, device_id, should_be
                  , device_id, active_power
             FROM   t
             ORDER  BY 1,2'

            ,'VALUES (552), (553), (554)'
         ) AS t (ts int, active_power int, device_id int, should_be int
               , a int, b int, c int)
   WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY ts)
   ) sub
ORDER  BY ts;
```

Returns the desired result, and should perform well.
Note that this solution builds on a small, given list of devices - `(552, 553, 554)` in your example.

Basics about `crosstab()`:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

About extra columns:

- [Pivot on Multiple Columns using Tablefunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415446/pivot-on-multiple-columns-using-tablefunc/15421607#15421607)

Advanced crosstab-foo:

- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334)

Comment: I must say, the tablefunc functionality is really helpful.  I wish I had know about this earlier.

Comment: @user2505340: `crosstab()` deals with complex logic that's confusing to some. But once you can wrap your mind around it, you can get fast and compact queries. If you have more use cases - I posted [quite a few comprehensive answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A939860+[crosstab]) over the past year or so.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach works if you know the value of "N".  It calculates the maximum `time` value for each of the devices, then joins back in the original records, and sums them using aggregation:

```
select tae.time, tae.value, taw.device,
       SUM(coalesce(dev.value)) as sumvalue
from (select t.*,
             MAX(case when device = 1 then time end) over (order by time) as dev1time,
             MAX(case when device = 2 then time end) over (order by time) as dev2time,
             MAX(case when device = 3 then time end) over (order by time) as dev3time
      from timeseries.total_active_energy tae
     ) tae left outer join
     timeseries.total_active_energy dev
     on dev.time in (dev1time, dev2time, dev3time)
group by tae.time, taw.value, tae.device;
```